# Laravel 5.0 Commands

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

So after watching the following video about 8 times things started to click in my head. Now I'm somewhat understanding how the purpose of commands and how to deal with them either self handling or whether there's a handler class for performing this task. I still have a couple of questions though before I dive into trying to wrap my head around Events.

https://laracasts.com/lessons/laravel-5-commands

Questions

1. From the way I've coded this. Does it look like I'm getting it or am
   I still missing something important?
2. In the CreateUserCommandHandler with the call to the create method
   on the user repository inside the handle method is that how I should
   be sending my data to the repository?

**Code**

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Repositories\Users\UserRepository;
use App\Repositories\Roles\RoleRepository;
use App\Commands\CreateUserCommand;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Requests\UserRequest;
use Illuminate\HttpResponse;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class UsersController extends Controller {

    private $userRepository;
    private $roleRepository;

    /**
     * @param UserRepository $userRepository
     * @param RoleRepository $roleRepository
     */
    public function __construct(UserRepository $userRepository, RoleRepository $roleRepository)
    {
        $this->userRepository = $userRepository;
        $this->roleRepository = $roleRepository;
    }

    /**
     * Save a new user.
     *
     * @param UserRequest $request
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function store(UserRequest $request)
    {
        // formally had $this->userRepository->create($request->all());
        $this->dispatchFrom(CreateUserCommand::class, $request);

        return redirect('users');
    }

}

<?php namespace App\Commands;

use App\Commands\Command;

class CreateUserCommand extends Command {

    public $first_name;
    public $last_name;
    public $display_name;
    public $email;
    public $password;
    public $role_id;

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($first_name, $last_name, $display_name, $email, $password, $role_id)
    {
        $this->first_name = $first_name;
        $this->last_name = $last_name;
        $this->display_name = $display_name;
        $this->email = $email;
        $this->password = $password;
        $this->role_id = $role_id;
    }

}

<?php namespace App\Handlers\Commands;

use App\Commands\CreateUserCommand;

use App\Repositories\Users\UserRepository;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;

class CreateUserCommandHandler {

    /**
     * @var UserRepository
     */
    private $userRepository;

    /**
     * Create the command handler.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(UserRepository $userRepository)
    {
        //
        $this->userRepository = $userRepository;
    }

    /**
     * Handle the command.
     *
     * @param    $command
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(CreateUserCommand $command)
    {
        $this->userRepository->create($command);
    }

}
```

Comment: Well, yes, that's basically how you do it, but **1.** don't fall into the trap of using commands for *everything* - I don't think this level of complexity makes much sense for your example. Don't feel bad for calling a repo or doing validation in the controller - in most cases that's perfectly fine. **2.** I don't think your user-repository should have knowledge of a command class. What happens if you decide to rename it or just completely drop it? Even though the Command is just a simple DTO, you should just pass e.g. a simple array of data to the repo and let the repo handle it.

Comment: What about events though? Should I do the repo create method in my event then?

Comment: Well, again, yes, you absolutely *could* do that, but that doesn't mean you *should*. Think about it - what would you call the event? I can't think of an appropriate name. Just create the user (which is the main task of this command), and *then* you might want to fire an event, e. g.  'UserCreated' so other handlers who are listening could hook into that. But once again, take some time to think about if you *really need* this level of complexity. Start simple, and if you hit some boundaries, you can break them with concepts like this. Only use them if you really know what for.